# Compare two text file or csv files by powershell

Tags: powershell, csv, compare

Hi Powershell Experts,

I am stuck with my script. It gives me no error but i am not getting desired output.

I have two files text file or csv file. It depends upon me which file i required i have both option my data is in string value and single column only so, it can be text or csv whichever is required. I have to compare the file each line with another file. No matter data is located on which line. It will have to compare every line every time. I tried many times but i am not getting desired output. I tried to compare it as text or csv but all the times it is not giving me output as require.

```
Here is my code :(

$csv2 = "C:\Users\Desktop\Log\Threat_report.01232014195755.txt" 

$csv1 = "C:\Users\Desktop\Log\Threat_report.txt"

Compare-Object -ReferenceObject (get-content -path $csv1) -DifferenceObject (get-content -path $csv2)| export-csv "C:\Users\Desktop\Log\Threat_Report.csv" -NoTypeInfo
```

sample data File 1

ONTAP_ADMIN$\vol\ABCDEF\Groupdata$\Central_Resource_Publish\Temp data Menu\~$temp aResource Menu.xlsm

ONTAP_ADMIN$\vol\ABCDEF\Groupdata$\Central_Resource_Publish\Temp data Menu\~$temp Rsfsesource Menu.xlsm

Sample data file 2

ONTAP_ADMIN$\vol\ABCDEF\Groupdata$\Central_Resource_Publish\Temp data Menu\~$temp Nomenu Menu.xlsm

ONTAP_ADMIN$\vol\ABCDEF\Groupdata$\Central_Resource_Publish\Temp data Menu\~$temp aResouserce Menu.xlsm

ONTAP_ADMIN$\vol\ABCDEF\Groupdata$\Central_Resource_Publish\Temp data Menu\~$temp Rsfsesource Menu.xlsm

ONTAP_ADMIN$\vol\ABCDEF\Groupdata$\Central_Resource_Publish\Temp data Menu\~$temp Rsfsesouaferce Menu.xlsm

When i compare the file. Script is working fine but when i shuffle the data it export  entire data in csv file like match not found. It seems like it is only comparing line 1 to line 1, line 2 to line 2 so on. It doesn't check like line 1 to line 1, 2, 3 , 4 ...
Please advise me how to resolve this issue.

Comment: Please provide a reduced test case for your issue. Thanks.

Comment: Hello Neolisk,thanks for your quick reply. Could you please advise me what would be the reduced test. I am not getting you. Appologies.

Comment: Sometimes referred to as [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), it's something we can run on our machines to verify the behavior you are experiencing. For example, we don't have your files, obviously, so please provide a way to reproduce the relevant parts of your file structure. See [more about reduced test cases](http://css-tricks.com/reduced-test-cases/).

Comment: Are you wanting to compare each line in file 1 against every line in file 2?

Comment: I want to compare every line from first file with second file. If value not match in entire file then i will export the value to different file as output. If value match then i will ignore it.

Comment: Hi Neolisk, I had given the sample file value. The data is same as sample in both file.

Comment: What version of Powershell are you using?

Comment: @mjolinor: I am using Powershell version 2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this close to what you want?

```
@'
ONTAP_ADMIN$\vol\ABCDEF\Groupdata$\Central_Resource_Publish\Temp data Menu\~$temp aResource Menu.xlsm 
ONTAP_ADMIN$\vol\ABCDEF\Groupdata$\Central_Resource_Publish\Temp data Menu\~$temp Rsfsesource Menu.xlsm
'@ | set-content file1.txt

@'
ONTAP_ADMIN$\vol\ABCDEF\Groupdata$\Central_Resource_Publish\Temp data Menu\~$temp Nomenu Menu.xlsm 
ONTAP_ADMIN$\vol\ABCDEF\Groupdata$\Central_Resource_Publish\Temp data Menu\~$temp aResouserce Menu.xlsm 
ONTAP_ADMIN$\vol\ABCDEF\Groupdata$\Central_Resource_Publish\Temp data Menu\~$temp Rsfsesource Menu.xlsm
ONTAP_ADMIN$\vol\ABCDEF\Groupdata$\Central_Resource_Publish\Temp data Menu\~$temp Rsfsesouaferce Menu.xlsm
'@ | set-content file2.txt

$base = get-content file1.txt

get-content file2.txt |
where {$base -notcontains $_} |
set-content diff.txt

get-content diff.txt

ONTAP_ADMIN$\vol\ABCDEF\Groupdata$\Central_Resource_Publish\Temp data Menu\~$temp Nomenu Menu.xlsm 
ONTAP_ADMIN$\vol\ABCDEF\Groupdata$\Central_Resource_Publish\Temp data Menu\~$temp aResouserce Menu.xlsm 
ONTAP_ADMIN$\vol\ABCDEF\Groupdata$\Central_Resource_Publish\Temp data Menu\~$temp Rsfsesouaferce Menu.xlsm
```

Answer (score 0):

This is untested, but it should get you close to what you want.

```
$Origin = Import-Csv "C:\Users\Desktop\Log\Threat_report.01232014195755.txt"
$Compare = Import-Csv "C:\Users\Desktop\Log\Threat_report.txt"

$Origin | % {
    $Source = $_
    [bool]$SourceFound = $false
    $Compare | % {
        #This will compare each row in Origin against each row in $Compare.
        #What do you want to do with the results?
        if(!$SourceFound)
        {
            if((Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $Source -DifferenceObject $_) -eq "==")
            {
                $SourceFound = $true
            }
        }
    }
    if(!$SourceFound)
    {
        #Here you Write-Output because $Source was not found
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi websch01ar, thanks for your reply. I want to get the list of unmatched text lines in csv or text file.

Comment: Then I would just change how SourceFound is treated.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your input in winmerge...are the typos meant to be there?  None of the lines match.  One of the lines says aresource and the "match" says aResouserce.

With your new input, I created two text files df1.txt and df2.txt.

```
 # Possible problem: what if the lines are not unique in the files?
 #  If this is the case, you'd have to not do the TODOs 
 #    or unique the lists before comparing them

 $csv1 = get-content -path ".\df1.txt"
 $csv2 = get-content -path ".\df2.txt"

 $list1      = new-object 'system.collections.generic.list[string]'
 $list2      = new-object 'system.collections.generic.list[string]'
 $listshared = new-object 'system.collections.generic.list[string]'

 $found = $false

 foreach ($line1 in $csv1)
 {
$found = $false
foreach ($line2 in $csv2)
{
    if ($line1 -eq $line2)
    {
        $listshared.add($line1)
        $found = $true
        # TODO: subtract $line1 from $csv1
        # TODO: subtract $line2 from $csv2
        break
    }
}

if (-not $found) 
{
    # TODO: subtract $line1 from $csv1
    $list1.add($line1)
}
 }

 # $csv1 and csv2 should be converted into real lists 
 # so they can be shrunk every time a match is found to reduce comparisons here
 foreach ($line2 in $csv2)
 {
$found = $false
foreach ($line1 in $csv1)
{
    if ($line1 -eq $line2)
    {
        # $listshared should be built at this point, just looking for uniques
        $found = $true
        break
    }
}
if (-not $found)
{
    $list2.add($line2)
}
 }

Write-Host "Things only in file 1:"
$list1

Write-Host "Things only in file 2:"
$list2

Write-Host "Things shared between the two files:"
$listshared
```

Output for me:
H$ .\comp.ps1

Things only in file 1:
ONTAP_ADMIN$\vol\ABCDEF\Groupdata$\Central_Resource_Publish\Temp data Menu\~$temp aResource Menu.xlsm

Things only in file 2:

ONTAP_ADMIN$\vol\ABCDEF\Groupdata$\Central_Resource_Publish\Temp data Menu\~$temp Nomenu Menu.xlsm
ONTAP_ADMIN$\vol\ABCDEF\Groupdata$\Central_Resource_Publish\Temp data Menu\~$temp aResouserce Menu.xlsm
ONTAP_ADMIN$\vol\ABCDEF\Groupdata$\Central_Resource_Publish\Temp data Menu\~$temp Rsfsesouaferce Menu.xlsm

Things shared between the two files:

ONTAP_ADMIN$\vol\ABCDEF\Groupdata$\Central_Resource_Publish\Temp data Menu\~$temp Rsfsesource Menu.xlsm

Comment: I am putting some more line in the sample now.